# Customizing tweet view using Fabric SDK

Tags: android, twitter, sdk

I'm starting to use Fabric (Twitter SDK) for my Android developments, but after investigating for some hours I can't find the way to customize the tweet view (e.g. remove the profile pic, the onClick event, etc).

The [documentation](http://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/show-tweets.html) only explains how to customize the style, but it isn't what I want.

Is there any way to add/remove elements from the tweet view offered by Fabric? Should I have to move to another library (e.g. Twitter4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently also exploring the TweetUI kit provided by Fabric. After digging into the TweetView and the BaseTweetView, I noticed that they don't offer any flexibility regarding removing/hiding views from the Tweet item. My issue was with the Share button for starter, that you can hide when you use the CompactTweetView (so it's not basically an option). I'm gonna try wrapping the BaseTweetView to see where I can go with this and will let you know.

Regarding other libraries likes Twitter4j (that was the most powerful 3rd party Twitter SDK so far), it depends on your need. Using Twitter4j requires the user to login in order to use the Twitter functionalities. If that doesn't bother you, go for it. In my case, I'm displaying embed tweets so it won't be a good UX.

Do keep in mind that you can display a fully custom Tweet UI since the SDK provides a Tweet object from an ID. So you can stop there, and display the Tweet UI you need.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really helpful for me, I will move to Twitter4j. In addition, a staff from Twitter replied me: "At this point, customization is limited to styling. We are considering other options/functionality, and will report back here when we have more.".